# Unicable usb receiver with multiple tuners

Tags: usb, hdtv

I want to build up a tvheadend server with 4 possible clients over unicable. So i have a unicable source with 4 channels which i want to pass to a server. Is there any affordable usb receiver, which can handle input from 1 cable with four simultaneous streams of DVBS2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For everyone with the same problem: i did it with an extra sat>ip server, the digibit r1. It can be used in tvheadend seamlessly.